# How I can access instance from MethodInfo

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a method receiving a function, usually a method. From that function I can access to the method's class and other stuff using MethodInfo.
I want to be able to access the instance used, if any, when passing the function/method.

Example:

```
MyFunctionReceivingAMethod(new SomeClass().MethodA)
```

I want to access at `MyFunctionReceivingAMethod` to `SomeClass` instance from `MethodA`'s reflection data. Is that possible?

Update:

I know I can pass the reference to the method but I wonder if its possible to get it using the funtion pointer I already have.

Comment: No, you cannot get instance information from a MethodInfo, because there is no such data attached. Maybe you should ask a question on how to do what you want to do. I think Reflection is not the best way to do it.

Comment: *using the funtion pointer I already have* You don't have a function pointer, which would be a delegate instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reflection data in the [`MethodInfo` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) are associated with the method in general, not with any particular instance. Thus, you can't get the information you're looking for from that class.

Instead, the [`Delegate.Target` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.target.aspx) will return the instance associated with the received delegate (which I'm assuming is what you're looking for). According to its description on MSDN, the property returns:

> The object on which the current delegate invokes the instance method, if the delegate represents an instance method; null if the delegate represents a static method.

Comment: What if I want to load all the methods from an assembly? How can I avoid getting the `MethodInfo[]` of `Type.Getmethods()`?